# Как обрабатывать нечитаемые символы?

Tags: python

Есть файл формата `csv`. В нём есть символы в какой-то неведомой кодировке. Задача удалить их и сделать информацию читаемой.

`file.read()` - выдаёт ошибку:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 18068: character maps to `<undefined>`

`csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')` - тоже фэйлится (ещё раньше).
Попытки читать в какой-то конкретной кодировке, приводят к ухудшению результата.

Соответственно вопрос. Как можно обработать (удалить, проигнорировать) символ, если программа вылетает при его прочтении?

Попробовал через `try/except` - они ничего не дают, программа всё равно прекращает работу при ошибке.

Comment: Добавте прямо в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: Что такое file, что такое tsvin? Покажите то, что у вас есть сейчас, будем двигаться от этого

Comment: "Как обрабатывать нечитаемые символы?" - первый вариант - открывать файл с указанием правильной кодировки, второй - обрабатывать файл как бинарный. В любом случае добавьте в вопрос ваш код и пример входных данных.

Answer (score 1):

С такой ошибкой приходится сталкиваться, когда читаешь данные записанные в кодировке [cp1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_Windows-1251). Некоторые программы типа Word или Excel могут писать символ с таким кодом, хотя в стандарте кодировки он отсутствует, что и приводит к указанному исключению в Python при попытке его конвертации в unicode.

Решение может быть, например открыть в бинарном режиме и заменять этот символ на что-нибудь другое:

```
with open('file_name.csv', 'rb') as csv_input:
  reader = csv.reader((li.replace('\x98', ' ').decode('cp1251') for li in csv_input), delimiter=';')
```

Или, как показали в предыдущем ответе, открыть файл с указанием игнорить все нераспознанные символы (python v3):

```
with open('file_name.csv', encoding='cp1251', errors='ignore', newline='') as csv_input:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_input, delimiter=';')
```

Ну и delimiter и остальные настройки нужно установить в корректный для входного формата.

Answer (score 0):

ну, допустим, можете обрабатывать так:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('file.txt', encoding='utf-16', errors='ignore') as file:
    data = [data for data in file]
```

само собой, кодировку здесь нужно указывать правильную, ну и "непечатные" символы игнорируются совсем